# How do I persist session values in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, session, ihttphandler

I'm implementing `IHttpHandler` and `IRequiresSessionState` and I'm using `context.Session` but after I set up a value in Session, it's lost in the next request. What can I do to persist the values ?

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/test.test", 
        type: "POST",
        data: "{'type':'GetStep'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {...}
 });
```

The second call is similar to this, but the values that get set when I call this function are also lost on the next request.

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
{
    context.Session ["Game"] = new Game (); // next time it is null
}
```

How do I persist values in Session state in ASP.NET ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "next time"?  Is it the very next page request?

Comment: Yes, I do another ajax call from javascript.

Comment: context.Session ["Game"] = new Game (); // next time context.Session["Game"] is null.

Comment: From your description, that is the correct code (assuming `Game` class is marked as [Serializable] if not using InProc SessionState). You must post more code/context for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have session state defined in your web.config?  Something like this

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
```