# Session values lost in an ASP.NET application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, session, ihttphandler

I created HttpHandler class in ASP.NET and configured a website to handle any request with the *.test path.

```
public class GameHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.ContentType == "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        {
            ...
            switch (parameters ["type"])
            {
                case "Setup":
                    result = Setup (context);

                    break;

                case "DoStep":
                    result = DoStep (context, parameters);

                    break;
             }
             ...
         }
         else
             context.Response.Write (@"
                  <html>
                      <head>
                      </head>
                      <body>
                          <!-- some HTML -->
                      </body>
                  </html>"); // this is returned on first request 
    }
```

In the Setup method I have such a code:

```
context.Session ["Game"] = new Game ();
```

In the DoStep method however, context.Session.Count = 0 and context.Session["Game"] is NULL.
In client side I use jquery to call these functions. Such a call looks like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/test.test",  
        type: "POST",
        data: "{'type':'Setup'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {...}
 });

 $.ajax({
        url: "/test.test",  
        type: "POST",
        data: "{'type':'DoStep','row':'" + row + "','column':'" + column + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {...}
 });
```

I suspect the problem is that ASP.NET doesn't know these requests sent from javascript belong to the same session and that's why the Session values are lost. I think that I would need to send back some cookie information or something for the next request to be identified but the fact is I don't have any idea.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: maybe you can compare the session ID from the server, and the one you have on the client (cookie, url)?

Comment: EDIT: isnt this a dup of the question you asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245868/how-do-i-persist-session-values-in-asp-net)?

Comment: Yes it is the same problem, but here I described it more deeply and I haven't got any good answers so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone encounters this problem I would like to specify that this happened because I use some file manipulation in the ProcessRequest method.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load (@"c:\XO_Game_Website\bin\test.xml"); 
if (context.Session ["something"] == null) 
{ 
    context.Session.Add("something", "something"); 
    doc.Root.Element ("xxx").Value = "null"; 
} 
else 
{
    doc.Root.Element ("xxx").Value = "not null";
}
doc.Save("path");
```

Once I removed the doc.Save("path"); from the method, everything just worked fine. Nonetheless I can't figure out why on earth would the file manipulation code reset the session values.

Happy coding.

Comment: If you change files in the bin folder, the application restarts (you could have put new/altered dll's there that are needed). On app-restart, *all* sessions are cleared.

Comment: I had the same problem but I was not writing to the bin folder.... I was creating a new folder but it also implied in the the application restart. This post saved the day.